# If client sends connection close header could server to resonse with payload?

Tags: http, keep-alive, chunked-encoding

I am testing my proxy server and have got a problem with connection close header from the client. If I try to response from the server with identity transfer-encoding it's limited with 390 bytes. After reading wireshark I decided that the my problem came from the limits of the tcp.reassembled.length and 390 payload is matches for the 512 of tcp.reassembled.length. Chunked responses doesn't work at all.

As I understand, if the client sends connection-close header the server should answer with only one packet and the sending payload is an undefined behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

"As I understand, if the client sends connection-close header the server should answer with only one packet and the sending payload is an undefined behaviour?"

Not, it means that the server should send the full response and then close the connection.